# php Date() returns wrong day and time

Tags: php

I have this code to test what's going on:

```
echo date('y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "<br/>";
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

The result is:

```
18-05-28 11:27:11
Asia/Manila
```

Current Time in Asia/Manila is

```
18-05-27 8:28pm
```

So why does it returns the wrong date and time when i set the correct timezone?

Comment: Most likely the server's clock is wrong. Run an NTP sync.

Comment: The language takes the time from the OS, check your server/computer time and make sure it's correct

Comment: Yes the time is correct. Daniel. I am currently in Manila so i am using this time.

Comment: I'll look for it Niet.

Comment: What's `echo exec('date');` give back

Comment: Just for kicks n confirmation, before those echo's you have, add a setting of the timezone explicit, then try it: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');` (I doubt it would make a difference though... but this is screwy behavior you are seeing, so something is not set right somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for helping everyone. I realized the problem after doing exec('time 8:49:00 PM'); exec('date 5/26/2018'); suggested above. I have posted how i solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. It was windows problem.
Windows was actually using different timezone.
So setting the right timezone made things right.

[image]

Comment: Then `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');` should have solved the issue as well. It's a good practice to explicitly set the timezone in your code, so the code works on any server. Never assume that the server has the correct timezone.

Comment: I havent tried it. but I agree its a good practice. so i'll put it on top of my code. :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Date uses the default value for `time()` which, as pointed out in the top comment on php manual, defaults to UTC.

See the php manual here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Modifying to `strftime(‘%F %T’, mktime())` will solve this.

Comment: fyi ‘%F’ is yyyy-mm-dd and ‘%T’ is hh:mm:ss

Comment: A notice is thrown when this is the case `Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings...`

Comment: True. There is a way to get the local time as an array and pass this as a string to mktime(), although this may be a bit overkill.